# acro package only printing long forms (if forced, can print short forms)

Tags: bugs, acro

Hello dear Stackexchangers,
I'm a little stupefied by following problem. I'm using the acro package. When I call the acronyms with "\ac", it only prints the long forms. I have prepared a MWE:

```
\documentclass[final, 12pt, USenglish, a4paper, titlepage, BCOR=15mm, DIV=14, headsepline=false, footsepline=false, twoside, openany, cleardoublepage=empty,    listof=totoc, index=totoc, bibliography=totoc, numbers=noenddot, parskip=full, captions=tableheading]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{acro, longtable} 
\acsetup{list/template=longtable}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\DeclareAcronym{slta}{short = {SLTA}, long = {superlongtestacronym}}

\mainmatter

\ac{slta}\ac{slta}\ac{slta}\ac{slta}\\
\acs{slta}\acsp{slta}

\backmatter
\end{document}
```

The output is:

> superlongtestacronymsuperlongtestacronymsuperlongtestacronymsuperlongtestacronym
> SLTASLTAs

Any idea what could have gone wrong here? I'd rather have the standard behaviour of first printing the long form with the short one in captions, and the short one afterwards, unless specified otherwise.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you already try to place the `\DeclareAcronym` command in the preamble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the `\DeclareAcronym` command in the preamble of your document:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{acro, longtable} 
\acsetup{list/template=longtable}

\DeclareAcronym{slta}{short = {SLTA}, long = {superlongtestacronym}}
\begin{document}

\ac{slta} \ac{slta} \ac{slta} \ac{slta}

\acs{slta} \acsp{slta}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer! I could've sworn the place where I declare the acronyms once worked, never would've thought that was the mistake. Thank you!